# How do I get an accurate timing of a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, benchmarking

I am timing the difference between using a raw database and a snapshot.
I can time UDFs and views using this routine:

```
DECLARE @Loops INT SET @Loops = 1 
DECLARE @CPU INT SET @CPU = @@CPU_BUSY 
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
DECLARE @SelectedValue int

WHILE @Loops <= 100 
BEGIN

    EXEC @SelectedValue = CashFlow.usp_CSF_Report_ProjectedExpendituresByFundingParticipant '7/1/1999'
    IF @SelectedValue = 50
            PRINT 1 
    SET @Loops = @Loops + 1   
END

PRINT 'usp_CSF_Report_ProjectedExpendituresByFundingParticipant' 
PRINT 'Total CPU time: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @@CPU_BUSY - @CPU)  
PRINT 'Total milliseconds: ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(ms, @StartDate, GETDATE())) 
PRINT ''
```

But when I run it with a stored procedure, as shown, I get the result set back.

I'm concerned that the time taken to display the results invalidate the timing results.

Tried wrapping it in a view or UDF, but I don't see any solution in that direction that doesn't add huge random overhead.

How can I capture or ignore the results so they don't display?

Comment: That is difficult to achieve, there are lots of condition that might invalidate your timing like the location of the snapshot and your DB. Can't you consider a certain amount of time reasonable to say your time result is still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a server side trace or extended events.

[Server side trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx)

[Extended events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630282.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best you'll probably be able to do is to insert the results into a table variable. So they're not transferred to the client. Of course you'd have to truncate that between each call.

That being said, if you're trying to do performance tuning, I'd consider using SET STATISTICS IO ON and SET STATISTICS TIME ON...this will tell you the number of logical disk reads and the CPU time.

Also take a look at the actual query execution plan. In my experience, whichever query has the lowest logical disk reads generally is the fastest.

Comment: I thought about using a temp table, but I was looking for a more generic solution that would work for any SP.  
Thanks for the tip on SET STATISTICS for performance timing when we get to that.